# Start/Stop/Resume all in one button with Angular Timer

Tags: angularjs, timer, angularjs-controller

Using the pre-built "Angular Timer" directives available [here](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer) (scroll down to progress bar example), I'm trying to build a progress bar with a Start, Stop and Resume button all-in-one.
Examples on their websites are made of two buttons and I would like to merge them.

One solution could be to use innerHTML to get the current state ("Start" or "Stop") and a if condition in the controller.js but i'd like the button to be a icon-only-button switching from play to pause icon.
An example from simple timer implementation is available [here](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer)

Here is my html

```
<button class="button button-icon icon" ng-class="{'icon ion-play': !play, 'icon ion-pause': play}" ng-click="stopResumeTimer(this)"></button>
<timer interval="1000" autostart="false"><div class="progress"> <div class="bar" style="width: {{seconds}}%;"></div> </div></timer>
```

And the controller.js code with the if condition

```
$scope.stopResumeTimer = function(btn) {
    if (not yet started) {
        $scope.startTimer();
    }
    else if (already started) {
        $scope.stopTimer();
    }
    else {
        $scope.resumeTimer();
    }
}
```

I am discouraged by the repeated failure on this, any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply store the state of the timer in the scope, as in http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/examples.html#/angularjs-single-timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fs5cpuoweEAkmWCQdWh3?p=preview))

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.operation = 'start';
  $scope.startOrStop = function(){
    document.getElementById('first')[$scope.operation]();
    $scope.operation = ($scope.operation === 'start' || $scope.operation === 'resume') ? 'stop' : 'resume';
  }
});
```

Declare it like this:

```
<button ng-click="startOrStop()" ng-class="{start:operation==='start', stop:operation==='stop', resume:operation==='resume'}"></button>
<timer id="first" interval="1000" autostart="false"><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{seconds}}%;"></div></div></timer>
```

Css:

```
.start::before{
  content:"Start";
}
.stop::before{
  content:"Stop";
}
.resume::before{
  content:"Resume";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edminsson, short and efficient solution!
I've tried to change text to icon (play/pause) by adding a class in ng-class for every state but it's not working.

ng-class="{start:operation==='start', 'icon ion-play':operation==='start'...

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve that? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In the controller where you are setting the ng-click function, you can set flags to determine whether the click function should start, stop, or resume. Those flags can also set the text for the button to be either "Start", "Stop", or "Resume".

JS:

```
(function(angular) {

  function controller($scope) {

    var isStart = false;
    var isStop = false;

    $scope.timerBtnText = "Start";

    $scope.timer = function() {
      if (isStart) {
        $scope.startTimer();
        isStart = false;
        isStop = true;
        $scope.timerBtnText = "Stop";
        return;
      } 

      if (isStop) {
        $scope.stopTimer();
        isStop = false;
        $scope.timerBtnText = "Resume";
      } else {
        $scope.resumeTimer();
        isStop = true;
        $scope.timerBtnText = "Stop";
      }
    };
  }

  angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", ["$scope", controller]);

})(angular);
```

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="timer()" ng-bind="timerText"></butotn>
```

Here is a working proof of concept: http://plnkr.co/edit/NlQFPysVH1M2EyjogQQv